# retryWhen operator with Hot Observable in RxJS

Tags: angular, firebase, rxjs, firebase-authentication, observable

The requirements is to get new value when auth token is expired and yet to keep it hot. Ideally in one observable variable (without separate Subject)

Currently the code looks as follows:

```
constructor(private angularFireAuth: AngularFireAuth) {}

private getAuthTokenResult(): Observable<firebase.auth.IdTokenResult> {
  return this.angularFireAuth.authState.pipe(
    switchMap(user => {
      if (user) {
        return from(user.getIdTokenResult(true));
      } else {
        return of(null);
      }
    })
  );
}

public authToken$: Observable<string> = this.getAuthTokenResult().pipe(
  map((result: firebase.auth.IdTokenResult) => {
    if (new Date() >= new Date(result.expirationTime)) {
      throw new Error('Token Expired');
    } else {
      return result.token;
    }
  }),
  retryWhen(errors =>
    errors.pipe(
      tap(() => console.log('Token Expired. Getting New One...')),
      delay(100),
      take(3)
    )
  ),
  shareReplay(1)
) as ConnectableObservable<string>;
```

But it doesn't do the job, after auth token is expired - it the new one is not received.

This is how the dependant service method looks like

```
addProduct(
  data: MerchantProductPartial
): Observable<MerchantProduct> {
  return this.authService.authToken$.pipe(
    switchMap(token => {
      // console.log('_addProduct', token);
      if (token) {
        const endpoint = ``;
        const httpOptions = {
          headers: new HttpHeaders({
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
          })
        };
        return this.http.post(endpoint, data, httpOptions);
      }
      else {
        throw new Error('Authorization Token not provided.');
      }
    })
  );
}
```

and the method execution as follows

```
this.merchantService.addProduct({
      name: 'New Test Product'
    }).pipe(take(1)).subscribe(res => console.log('res:', res), err => console.log('err:', err))
```

**SOLUTION**:

If anyone concerns about the solution - it simpler then I thought. Just need to use a different method https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#getIdToken which automatically updates invalid tokens... Just don't forceRefresh it...

```
public authToken$: Observable<string> = this.angularFireAuth.authState.pipe(
  switchMap(user: firebase.User => {
    if (user) {
      return from(user.getIdToken());
    } else {
      return of(null);
    }
  })
);
```

Comment: Isn't `authState` itself hot? Where are you actually trying to refresh the token?

Comment: `authState` is not hot. Its `Observable<firebase.User>`. As you see my idea to to: 1st check whether the token is invalidated, if it is - I am gonna re-grab the new one from the server - otherwise, I gonna use the previous one...

Comment: The docs seem to suggest otherwise: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/src/auth/auth.ts#L20. It seems that `authState` is only triggered on login/out so I don't think it will work as a mechanism to detect token expiry.

Comment: Indeed @paulpdaniels... Although I was too creative with my approach... As it turns our firebase has the function for my purpose https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#getIdToken - automatically updates expired token. I was too creative....